# HTTPS with WCF for machine names instead of IP-Adresses

Tags: wcf, https

I'm trying to set up my self-hosted WCF service to function over HTTPS. I roughly did as described in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24027/SSL-with-Self-hosted-WCF-Service):

1. I created a certificate for me as CA
2. I created a certificate for SSL using the CA certificate from the first step.
3. I used `netsh` to register my machine's IP address and the service's port for HTTPS

In 3. I used my machine's public IP address, as I'm testing SSL communication from a mobile device within the same WLAN. Things work fine, the client can talk to the server.

Now I also want to test from my local machine using another client. So I did 1. to 3. again, but for `CN=localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in step 3. Things also work fine if I access the service through `https://127.0.0.1`. However, when I try to use `https://localhost` I get an error that the registration with HTTPS.SYS may be missing - and it is, as I need to use an IP-address in above step 3.

My question is: While it is not much of a problem using the IP-address instead of the machine name, what would I have to do to allow access to my WCF service by machine name?

Comment: Does the cert use the machine name or localhost as its subject?

Comment: The first certificate I made to test with my external IP hat the external IP as subject. The second one has the subject `localhost`, but doesn't work when I address `https://localhost`, but does work when I address `https://127.0.0.1`.